# How to create a function which measures time performance of algorithms?

Tags: swift

If I want to evaluate time performance of a few algos using `Date()` or `Dispatch()` how can I create a function that does this?

For example this binary search algo. How can I pass it as a closure parameter and have the closure do all of the time performance measuring using any of the Swift time keeping methods below? Please answer with an example of a closure. Thanks.

`let startingPoint = Date()`
`let startingPoint = Dispatch().now`

```
    func binarySearchForValue(searchValue: Int, array: [Int]) -> Bool {

    var leftIndex = 0
    var rightIndex = array.count - 1

    while leftIndex <= rightIndex {

        let middleIndex = (leftIndex + rightIndex) / 2
        let middleValue = array[middleIndex]

    if middleValue == searchValue {
        return true
    }

    if searchValue < middleValue {
        rightIndex = middleIndex - 1
    }

        if searchValue > middleValue {
            leftIndex = middleIndex + 1
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: I have rewritten my question. If you could delete your comment that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: My “go to” solution for benchmarking something very quickly and easily is to create unit test, and then use [`measure`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1496290-measure). Note, you might want to repeat this enough times to make measurement time observable and significant.

Comment: You keep using the word closure. It doesn’t mean what you seem to think it does. Thus the intent of your question is very unclear.

Comment: Ok so I changed the title to say function instead of closure. However I do not think that my code is, as you put it,  "meaningless". There are already two good answers. Somehow they got exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you may want to measure different functions, it probably makes sense to capture the arguments for the function in the closure instead of including their types in the signature. But I did use a generic type for the return value. I hope that this is what you're after:

```
func measure<R>(_ label: String, operation: () -> R) -> R {
  let start = DispatchTime.now()
  let result = operation()
  let end = DispatchTime.now()
  let nanoTime = end.uptimeNanoseconds - start.uptimeNanoseconds
  let timeInterval = Double(nanoTime) / 1_000_000_000
  print(String(format: "%@: %.9f s", label, timeInterval))
  return result
}
```

Here's how you use it:

```
let result = measure("search") { binarySearchForValue(searchValue: 3, array: [1, 3, 8]) }
print(result) // that's the result of the function that was measured, not the measurement

measure("some function") { functionWithoutReturnValue() }
```

If the function has no return value, `R` will be `()`, so that should work too. Just don't assign the result to anything (see the example above). If you want to do something with the measurement other than printing it to the console, you can do that, too. But you didn't specify that in your question, so I went with `print`.

Comment: Yes you are right. If I use a Bubble Sort for example I get a warning `Constant 'timeResult' inferred to have type '()', which may be unexpected` and the result is `()` as you said. But I still get the time measurement. I have added a label like this `func measure<R>(operation: (_ boolResult: Bool) -> R) -> R {...}` Is this what you're saying? Could you please add the label to your answer? I will mark it as the correct answer because your function is more versatile.

Comment: I added the label parameter to show what I meant. I also clarified how you use it for functions that have no return value: just don't assign the result to anything.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. p.s. I just ate some cake and ice cream :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you are after here and this solution below will only fit one specific function signature to test

```
func testBench(search: Int, array: [Int], testCase test: (Int, [Int]) -> Bool) {
    let start = DispatchTime.now()
    test(search, array)
    let end = DispatchTime.now()

    print("\(start) - \(end)")
}
```

called like this

```
testBench(search: 3, array: [6,7,5,3]) {binarySearchForValue(searchValue: $0, array: $1)}
```

Comment: This works. It only fits one specific function so I have marked mistercake's solution as correct since it uses Generics and is a one-stop-shop. Plus the time is calculated instead of an expression. I will still upvote your answer because it works as advertised. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You should use XCTest to measure the performance ... It gives you proper stats for your method in terms of performance

i.e.

```
func testMyCodesPerformance() {
    measureBlock {
        someClass.doSomethingFancy()
    }
}
```

[image]

You can do lot more using XCTest [measureBlock](https://nshipster.com/xctestcase/) for performance testing

Comment: Wow. I really need to practice TDD.  This is so badass.  Wish I could mark two correct answers. I see you used `someClass`. Can we just pass in functions/algos to test or do we need to create a class first that contains all of the functions/algos? What if I'm using algos in a playground without classes?

Comment: You can ... just import XCTest

Comment: https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/measureblock-how-does-performance-testing-work-in-ios-c1424eceb208